# How are ties broken in AuFS with the top-down-parent file creation policy?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, linux-kernel

The [AuFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) [manual](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs3/man.html#Policies%20to%20Select%20One%20among%20Multiple%20Writable%20Branches) says:

> Policies for Creating
>   create=tdp | top−down−parent
>
> ```
> Selects the highest writable branch where the parent dir exists. If
> the parent dir does not exist on a writable branch, then the internal
> copyup will happen. The policy for this copyup is always ’bottom-up.’
> This is the default policy.
> ```

What happens if there are multiple writable branches in which the parent directory exists?